# access sub array item via index

Tags: php, arrays

I am not a php developer and struggling to fix something unfortunately.

This is my object :-

```
"prx_replacement" => array(
        "ComforTone" => array(
            'img' => '/content/images/prx/comfortone.jpg',
            'description' => '<em>ComforTone</em>: Reduce acoustic noise and enhance MR patient experience'
        ),
        "ScanWise Implant" => array(
            'img' => '/content/images/prx/scanwise-implant.jpg',
            'description' => '<em>ScanWise Implant</em>: A key to confidence with MR Conditional implants'
        )
    )
```

I have an index value `$index`

I need to access `img` value dynamically using index number but could not manage it.

```
$lang['prx_replacement']["ComforTone"]["img"]
```

works but

`$lang['prx_replacement'][$index]["img"]` wont.

My code:

```
foreach( $case_solutions as $index => $solution ){
<img src="<?php echo $base_url.$lang['prx_replacement']["ComforTone"]["img"]?>" />
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How are you generating $index?

Comment: it is "foreach", it prints 0,1,2...

Comment: Can you show the code your using, it may clarify your problem.

Comment: Updated the question. That way works but it is not dynamic.

Comment: Chaneg $lang to $solution in foreach loop.

Comment: what is the value of `$index`?

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid no, that is not the issue.

Comment: @AlivetoDie 0,1,2..

Comment: I think you can use `array_values($lang['prx_replacement'])[$index]["img"]` (that will replace the array keys like ComforTone by an numeric index)  but it might not be the best solution to access an associative arary by an numeric index.

Comment: @xander, that worked indeed, thanks a lot!

Comment: ca you please show what is the value of $case_solutions

Comment: Thanks guys, @xander's comment helped me solve it actually. Not sure why i got 3 downvotes tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like below:-

```
<?php

$lang_array  = array(
    "prx_replacement" => array(
        "ComforTone" => array(
            'img' => '/content/images/prx/comfortone.jpg',
            'description' => '<em>ComforTone</em>: Reduce acoustic noise and enhance MR patient experience'
        ),
        "ScanWise Implant" => array(
            'img' => '/content/images/prx/scanwise-implant.jpg',
            'description' => '<em>ScanWise Implant</em>: A key to confidence with MR Conditional implants'
        )
));

$lang_array = array_values($lang_array['prx_replacement']);

foreach( $case_solutions as $index => $solution ){?>
    <img src="<?php echo $base_url.$lang_array[$index]['img'];?>" />
<?php }?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/843261 (on browser it will render image,don't worry)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `?>` to output raw HTML inside your `foreach`.

```
foreach( $case_solutions as $index => $solution ){ 
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $base_url.$lang['prx_replacement'][$index]["img"]?>" />
    <?php
}
```

Or for a simple one-liner, you can use `echo`

```
foreach( $case_solutions as $index => $solution ){ 
    echo '<img src="' . $base_url.$lang['prx_replacement'][$index]["img"] . '"';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop one level deeper using `$case_solutions["prx_replacement"]`

So, you code would look like:

```
<?php 
foreach( $case_solutions['prx_replacement'] as $index => $solution ){ ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $base_url.$lang['prx_replacement']["$index"]["img"]?>" />
<?php } ?>
```